# What is best practice for storing sensitive data in Store apps?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have an Store app. User can do some actions in exchange for some credits. More of the credits he can purchase by in-app-purchase. So I need to keep count of his credits safely. I don't want to use database because of need of internet connection and I don't want to use the value serialized to xml file, because it is totally unsafe. Is there something like CredentialManager where to safe such values?

Thanks for tips

Comment: You don't want to be storing that kind of information on the device. If they can buy credits, they can use the internet. SQLite is the standard local database, but you will want to keep a master record remotely for comparison.

Comment: They can buy credits when they are online, yes. But they then can use the credits offline.

Comment: so what stops me decompiling the app and inserting my own number for the amount of credits? anything device side could be modified by the user.

Comment: yeah, that's the point of my question :D I am asking if there is something like PasswordVault class or something like that which could be relatively safe to use or if only way is to use database...

Comment: DO NOT store data like that on the client. EVER. Store that kind of information remotely, using a service class to interface between the application and the database. You need to remain in control of this data, not the user. They just need accesss.

Comment: Ok, I get your point but think this scenario: there is a game, you have limited number of resources for the game, but you have coins which you can transform into resources of your choice. You can purchase more of the coins by inapp, but still you have the coins as your in-game currency even offline for your disposal. You must store this information locally. I agree, you can record changes and compare them with remotely stored values every time device is online, but still, you have to have these data stored locally. Haven't you?